# UIGestureRecognizer receives touch but doesnt execute action

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an MPMoviePlayerController which I add to a view with:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mpc = INIT and other stuff
[self.view addSubview:mpc.view];
```

In IB I've hooked up a tap gesture recognizer to a selector called `showhide:`.

I have a toolbar on the screen, and when it's touched it prevents the gesture from going through with:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (self.controlsVisable) {
        BOOL inbar = CGRectContainsPoint(self.controlBar.frame, touchedPoint);
        NSLog(@"inbar? %d", inbar);
        return !inbar;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And that works perfectly. If I tap in the bar, it prints `"inbar? 1"` and otherwise it prints `"inbar? 0"`. So clearly it is getting the touches. But it never executes `showhide:`.

To clarify, `showhide:` should fire only when I press outside of the bar. Also, regardless of if I tap inside or outside of the bar, `showhide:` never fires

Comment: Don't you want to return NO as the default value?

Comment: No. If the controls aren't visible then the tap should always go through

Comment: I see, I misread the condition.

Comment: Any other ideas on this?